# Extracting text between the <span> tags with xpath in Python

Tags: python, html, xpath

I'm trying to use python to extract a metric from a website: http://www.bild.de/regional/hamburg/mord/das-denkt-der-presserat-ueber-den-mord-an-unserer-tochter-lisa-41186944.bild.html

I need the text (number) under the yellow "LACHEN" button (now at 149). The XPath to that specific element is `//*[@id="jsm_16584"]/ul/li[1]/span`

However it does not return any object when I try to query it:

```
url = "http://www.bild.de/regional/hamburg/mord/das-denkt-der-presserat-ueber-den-mord-an-unserer-tochter-lisa-41186944.bild.html"
req=urllib2.Request(url)
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen(req).read())
metric=tree.xpath('//*[@id="jsm_16584"]/ul/li[1]/span')
print metric
```

It returns `metric` as an empty list.

Comment: The value you are after is updated dynamically with javascript. I don't think that you will be able to extract it with xpath.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with some other method?

Answer (score 0):

The **urlopen** is not executing any script you just get raw html so if the data are generated by javascript they are not rendered by using this method. Something like this should work:

```
import sys  
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  
from lxml import html

class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, url):  
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    self.app.exec_()  

  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
    self.app.quit()  

url = 'http://www.bild.de/regional/hamburg/mord/das-denkt-der-presserat-ueber-den-mord-an-unserer-tochter-lisa-41186944.bild.html'  
r = Render(url)  
page = r.frame.toHtml()

tree = html.fromstring(page)
metric=tree.xpath('//button[@class="btn-mood-1"]/@data-mood-count')

print(metric)
```